# The system cannot find the path specified in MPI

Tags: mpi, mpiexec

I am writing a sample program MPI in which one process send an integer to other process.

This is my source code

```
 #include <mpi.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   // Find out rank, size
   int world_rank;
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
   int world_size;
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

   int number;
   if (world_rank == 0) {
      number = -1;
      MPI_Send(&number, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
   }
   else if (world_rank == 1) {
      MPI_Recv(&number, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
        MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
      printf("Process 1 received number %d from process 0\n",
        number);
   }
}
```

And this is the error when I run mpiexec in windows cmd line

***ERROR: Error reported: failed to set work directory to 'D:\study_documents\Thesis\Nam 4\Demo\Sample Codes\MPI_HelloWorld\Debug' on DESKTOP-EKN1RD3
Error (3) The system cannot find the path specified.***

Comment: All errors should be within the question itself **as text**. They must be searchable. Also, your picture is so small that I can't read anything. Please copy and paste the error **as text**.

Comment: After you do that, tell us how you set up the MPI paths in your computer.

Comment: I set it up in path : "C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI..." And its SDK path is : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI..."

Comment: Does the path `D:\study_documents\Thesis\Nam 4\Demo\Sample Codes\MPI_HelloWorld\Debug` really exist? Check for typos.

Comment: Yes, because I save the project in it

Comment: Check for exact correspondence. Try to copy from here, paste and open. Show which exact command you are running, and where. How do you specify the working directory? Do you run `mpiexec` in that directory or somewhere else?

Comment: mpiexec MPI_HelloWorld.exe

Comment: And where?, please tell us us much details as you can. Edit the question and put the details in there. The MPI version, compiler, MPI paths, the way you used to set them... And please check if the path `D:\study_documents\Thesis\Nam 4\Demo\Sample Codes\MPI_HelloWorld\Debug` is **exactly** correct once more.

Comment: It's exactly correct because this path contains the program's file .exe to run by cmd. MPI paths and compiler are as I told you above. My MPI's version is 7.0 provided by Windows. The error is that The system cannot find the path specified, but I don't know how to specify it.

Comment: My cmd is : "mpiexec MPI_HelloWorld.exe". I use Visual Studio to program

Comment: Check the permissions to those directories.

Comment: When I change permissions of this directory to full control for all users, but it still doesn't work. D:\study_documents\Thesis\Nam 4\Demo\Sample Codes\MPI_HelloWorld\Debug

Comment: Try the same in a different directory. As simple as possible, no special characters orbspaces in the name.

Comment: No space in path, It works for me, thanks